# How to generate a tsv file from multiple tsv columns in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, text

I'm new to python and still learning. I have two `tsv` files formatted as follows:

File 1 (infile):

```
  16 cat    22  newData 1.0 u
    19 cat  27 newData  1.0 u
    2 dog   81  newData 1.0 u
    11 tiger 55 newData 1.0 u
```

File 2 (outfile):

```
99 fish 22  oldData 1.0 u
4 cat   27 oldData  1.0 u
2 turtle 81 oldData 1.0 u
1 lion  55  oldData 1.0 u
```

Desired output:

```
  99 fish   22  newData 1.0 u
   4 cat    27 newData  1.0 u
   2 turtle 81  newData 1.0 u
   1 lion  55   newData 1.0 u
```

I can read the new data successfully but fail to replace the oldData column by the newData, here is a sample code:

```
# Read new data    
with open('/path/to/new/data.tsv') as infile:
      newData = {}
        for line in infile:
            parts = line.decode('utf-8').split('\t')
            if len(parts) > 0:
                token = parts[0].strip()
                newData = parts[3]
                print(newData)
```

I'm working in python 2.7. How to generate a third file the has the columns [0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
from file 2 and column[3] from file 1?
Thank you,

Comment: If you are new to Python you should jump on 3.X. That is my opinion though.

Comment: @usr2564301 outfile is File 2 which has data in it as shown in the question. Please read carefully.

Comment: @AntonvBR You're right, thanks.

Comment: Well, then you are still using `write` wrong. Python cannot change 'lines' (or parts of lines) inside an existing file. You **must** read both `outfile` and `infile` to be able to combine them, and then create a third file as the final result.

Comment: (… and also: `for line in outfile` *still* does not make sense. It is opened for *output* and so you are not reading anything from it – neither lines nor something else. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: @usr2564301 This is a helpful comment. Thanks.

Comment: You can also look into [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)