# Write lists as columns in tsv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I have three lists which I wish to store in a tsv file as follows:

```
 1 a yes
 2 b no 
 3 c yes
```

The lists:

```
list1 = [u'1', u'2', u'3']
list2 = [u'a', u'b', u'c']
list3 = [u'yes', u'no', u'yes']
```

The following code stores it using a csv writer method:

```
rowlists = zip(list1, list2, list3)
writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
for row in rowlists:
     writer.writerow(row)
```

However, this method is causing some errors in later processing due to to format differences I guess between tsv and csv `SyntaxError: Got u'"\t1.0'`. So, is there another way to do it without the use of the csv writer? 
I'm using python 2.7.

Any help will be truly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: You should simply read the tsv file with the same `delimiter='\t'` argument for you `csv.reader`.

Comment: @blhsing  Thank you for your comment. Argument is the same. The whole idea is that I'm trying to read two columns from one tsv and one column from a tsv file and join all of them in a new tsv file. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176851/how-to-replace-column-values-of-a-tsv-file-in-python.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to use a writer, you could do this manually.  But note that managing quotes for columns that contain the delimiter would be a little hard:

Simplest method:

```
numItems = len(l1)
outputStr = ''

for i in range(0,numItems): 
  outputStr += l1[i] + "\t" + l2[i] + "\t" + l3[i] + "\n"


with open('output.tsv', "w") as outputter:
  outputter.write(outputStr)
```

If col data also contains a '\t', you'll have to search each list item and wrap it in quotes...can update if necessary.

If there are unicode characters, you can define that in the writing operation when you open the file.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you. problem remains. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176851/how-to-replace-column-values-of-a-tsv-file-in-python

Comment: Thank you for the link and for your comment.  I am having a little trouble understanding why there is a problem or where it lives.  The process seems somewhat straight forward....read from both files, break them into an array of arrays. Construct a new array of arrays. and delete. Perhaps you can pull out the relevant subset of your code and the "old" and "new" data files and share a github link? That way, we can look at the code and see the bug with the right context.

Answer (score 0):

`csv.writer` needs to be passed a open file object

```
with open(outfile, 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in rowlists:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to read two columns from one tsv and one column from a tsv file and join all of them in a new tsv file. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176851/how-to-replace-column-values-of-a-tsv-file-in-python